# Passing code text in post ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I'm using a pure javascript code and i'm sending a post ajax request using XMLHttpRequest.
I have a text variable with a php code in it (multi-lines).

How can i pass this variable to the request ? (The problem is the new lines and some signes like &)

Thanks

Comment: Add some code, what you have tried...

Comment: Just store the code in a hidden form field and submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode them using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) javascript function. For example:

```
var dataToPost = 'param1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + 
                 '&param2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2) + 
                 '&param3=' + encodeURIComponent(value3);
```

Now the values could contain any characters. They will be properly url encoded and safe to be sent with the request either as POST or GET.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason i used encodeURIComponent but decided its not suitable for me. After your reply checked again and returned to use it - Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this example and customize it as your needs

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

you can see this page for more details 
 http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

------------ this is Java script code --------------

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford"); // here you can send data
```

Comment: Did someone mention jQuery? Quote from the question: `I'm using a pure javascript code and i'm sending a post ajax request using XMLHttpRequest`.